# @Autowired es null o @Service no está permitido

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

Estoy desarrollando la seguridad en Springboot, necesito comprobar el usuario que me envían con la base de datos, pero el repositorio se crea a null.

El problema viene porque "la clase" se crea de manera manual "new LoginFilter"
Entonces el SpringBoot no "scaneó" el componente y lo rellenó antes del arranque.

Estoy intentando varias cosas, en ambas tengo problemas:

1. Que springboot scanee y lo rellene antes del arranque.
2. Que gestione el springboot la creación de la clase.

Me da igual cuál solución ha implementar, mientras que funcione...

Intentando springboot scanee y lo rellene antes del arranque:

La petición es recogida por:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "es....")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //permitimos el acceso a /login a cualquiera
        .anyRequest().authenticated() //cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
        .and()
        // Las peticiones /login pasaran previamente por este filtro
        .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

        // Las demás peticiones pasarán por este filtro para validar el token
        .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Como se puede observar new LoginFilter, es creado manualmente, por eso mismo, cuando se crea la clase en runtime, @autowired y @value serán nulls.

```
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {   

    @Autowired
    private RolesUserRepository rolRepository; // es null

    @Value("${ldap.base}")
    private String base; // es null

    public LoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        // obtenemos el body de la peticion que asumimos viene en formato JSON
        InputStream body = req.getInputStream();

        // Realizamos un mapeo a nuestra clase User para tener ahi los datos
        User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, User.class);

        // Finalmente autenticamos
        if (user.getUsername().equals("edu")) { // no puedo usar el repo porque es null
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList()));
        }
        throw new javax.security.sasl.AuthenticationException("Credenciales inválidas.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Si la autenticacion fue exitosa, agregamos el token a la respuesta
        JwtUtil.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

Aquí lo que intentado es crear en la clase las diferentes anotaciones para que al arranque de springboot, rellene "@"

```
@Service @Component @Configuration etc
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
```

He probado muchos @Algo pero me da el error de:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Parameter 0 of constructor in es....config.LoginFilter required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

Intentando crear el `public LoginFilter(){}` pero no está permitido.

Lo otro que intenté es:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "es....")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
LoginFilter loginFilter;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //permitimos el acceso a /login a cualquiera
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
            .and()
            // Las peticiones /login pasaran previamente por este filtro
            .addFilterBefore(this.loginFilter.attemptAuthentication("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)


    }
```

Nótese que ahora la creación ya no es manual sino con @Autowired.

Aquí lo que intento es llamar directamente al método `this.loginFilter.attemptAuthentication("/login", authenticationManager()` con la esperanza que el springboot haya rellenado los @autowired y @value de dentro.

Aquí el problema es que no puedo hacer la llamada al "login", se queja de los parámetros.

El código completo es:
https://windoctor7.github.io/spring-jwt.html

He hecho una modificación para que no coja los valores de la memoria del springboot, sino que obviamente tendrán que compararse con lo obtenido de la base de datos.

Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Al final lo resolví creando mi propio bean para que Springboot rellenase el objeto al arrancar:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "es....service")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LoginFilter createLogin() throws Exception {
        return new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //permitimos el acceso a /login a cualquiera
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
            .and()
            // Las peticiones /login pasaran previamente por este filtro
           .addFilterBefore(createLogin(),  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

            // Las demás peticiones pasarán por este filtro para validar el token
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {   

    @Autowired
    private RolesUserRepository rolRepository;

    @Value("${ldap.base}")
    private String base;
```

Comment: Estaba justo escribiendote una respuesta similar, me alegro que hayas encontrado la solución :)